# creating wrapper around apache camel kafka component to create multiple consumers and producers with different set of configurations

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I'm working on a spring boot application that will use apache camel kafka component used for integrations. The application will have multiple consumers and producers with different set of brokers and security configs. Goal here is to create a library which will allow devs to add properties in application yml and the kafkaEndpoint will be created dynamically which will be used for creating the routes and devs don't have to write the dsl or uri themselves for kafka endpoints.

what would be the best approach to achieve it, to give a standardized code which can be added as a dependency in a service and connection string will be created on the fly reading from application.yml

I tried extending the KafkaComponent, so that all properties are covered and if something changes in future i'll have to bump the apache version only rather than changing my class for configurations, but while creating the endpoint some of the properties are not supported by apache camel kafka component and getting error